# Adding suggestionItems Fails: "Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.SearchField"

Tags: sapui5

I am adding a SearchField with suggestions in the XML view. When I execute, I get the error

> Error: Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.SearchField.

Please tell me what mistake I am making.

```xml
<SearchField
  placeholder="final search"
  tooltip="Search for datastore source names"
  suggestionItems="{/records}"
  selectOnFocus="true"
>
  <suggestionItems>
    <SuggestionItem
      text="{dbname}"
      description="{dbname}"
    />
  </suggestionItems>
</SearchField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a look to this example

[sap.m.Input](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputAssisted/preview)

suggestionItems="{/ProductCollection}" is the collection with all the available entries, text="{Name}" is one of the attributes of the collection item.

Check this example without search help https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsDynamic/preview or https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsCustomFilter/preview

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution, I have copied the code in the example of SAPUI5 but gives me this same error. Have anyone come up with a real solution ? or why is this happening ?

Comment: @MauricioAlbertoBarragnHuert Here I explained why this is happening: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52512500](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52512500/5846045). Unfortunately, there can be only workarounds in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an old UI5 version. The aggregation [`suggestionItems`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SearchField/methods/getSuggestionItems) was introduced in 1.34.

> [image: sapui5 sap.m.SearchField suggestionItems available since]

Here, you can see that the app crashes throwing the same error if run with the version lower than 1.34: https://jsbin.com/qepojux/edit?html,js,output

To see with which UI5 version the app is currently running, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
See also *[Versioning of SAPUI5](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f021426f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)*.